# Why Variable is undefined in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node js express and calling model from the controller.When I call model form controller and getting a result in result variable and print it in `console.log(result)` it's `undefined`.

**Controller**

```
var user_model=require('../models/user');

exports.get_user = function(req, res) {

    var result = user_model.get_users();

    console.log(result);
}
```

**Model**

```
var connection=require('../config/connection');

exports.get_users = function() {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows) {
        if(err) {
            retrun err;
        }
        return rows;
    });
}
```

Comment: you have to write code for async call handle.

Comment: The problem is that the query result is being passed to a **callback** function, so the `return rows;` line will return the rows in the context of that function as opposed to the parent `get_users` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are consoling the result before the query has finished. Node is asynchronous. Unlike php node doesn't wait for the query to finish before going to the next line.

Comment: then what i will do

Comment: First thing is you can use promise for the same, but if you don't want to use promise then you can create method that will wait for the result i.e.

Comment: var connection=require('../config/connection');

exports.get_users = function() {


connection.query('SELECT * FROM users',function(err,rows ){
        if(err) {
            retrun err;
        }
        getData(rows);
    });
}

function getData(rows) {
   return rows;
}

Answer (score 1):

Use promise to handle async calls

```
// **Controller** 
var user_model = require('../models/user');

exports.get_user = function (req, res) {

    user_model.get_users().then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

// **Model** 
var connection = require('../config/connection');
exports.get_users = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(rows);
            });
        }
    })
}
```