# push mongoose query into a global array in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a beginner in nodejs and javascript in general. I want to access a collection and then store my query that I retrieve into an array so later I can do more stuff with that array. 
However, when I store the results in the array it doesnt outside the function. Here's my code

```
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const locations = require('./models/vicitmsLocation');
const async = require('async');


var postcode = [];

locations.getAllTheIncidents({},function (err, results) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
} else {

    postcode.push(results);
    //Here the code works and array will be populated with data I want
    console.log(postcode);
} 
});
//Here it doesnt work and array is empty.
console.log(postcode);
```

I understand that this might be an issue with async nature of nodejs and mongo but I cant seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: refer my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785020/why-variable-is-undefined-in-nodejs-express/48785124#48785124

Comment: I dont quite understand hows that gonna help in my case!

Comment: because of async nature, the last console executes before getAllTheIncidents callback returns data. So if your next code is dependent on the result of callback then you have to write inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

> Its because nodejs is nonblocking, So, the `console.log` outside is
>   being executed before the callback of `locations.getAllTheIncidents`
>   is executed.

So, you have to either use `postcode` inside the callback or bind `locations.getAllTheIncidents` inside a promise